# How to monitor a Windows process and send an alert when it crashes or closes?

Tags: windows, process, monitoring

I'm looking for a program/utility to monitor a process running in Windows 7 (actually it's a Java process ran from .jnlp). and that can send an e-mail alert or trigger any kind of script so I can be aware that it has crashed ?

From what i've seen there's nothing like that.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
:begin
tasklist | find "java.exe"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1  blat.exe ---
sleep 10
goto :begin
```

you'll need blat.exe which is the most used tool for sending mails via batch scripts
sleep should be built-in windows 7.
But this will work only if you have only one java.exe running...
You can use some external tools to start a process and its PID for maximum usability

Comment: Excellent ! Right what i was looking for; is it possible to get a .bat to run as a service ? I saw some applications around for .exe2service did you try .bat ?

Comment: may be this could help: http://runasservice.sourceforge.net

Comment: !!! I LOVE YOU :)

Comment: I like bmail too: http://retired.beyondlogic.org/solutions/cmdlinemail/cmdlinemail.htm like blat but much leaner and smaller. free too.