# Get a notification when a exe is not running anymore

Tags: windows-7, task-scheduler

I have a synchronization running in the background. I thought I'll find the answer within seconds, but somehow I am not able to do so.

I would like to get a notification when that program closes or is terminated, i.e. is not running for whatever reason.

I thought it should be possible to use the task scheduler for that with a trigger "when a specific event is logged", here the exe is closed.
But is there an event logged when a process is terminated? If yes where do I find it?

Comment: Try this: http://superuser.com/questions/445345/how-to-monitor-a-windows-process-and-send-an-alert-when-it-crashes-or-closes

Comment: Thanks, but this is a batch file that is visible (okay I found ways to run a batch file that it is not visible). Then I get an error with the sleep command, so it seems not to be a valid command!? So the result is that I see in the task manager a process cmd with a too high CPU usage.

Isn't there a simpler way, e.g. isn't it logged in the windows log when a exe terminates? Then I could use that event in the task scheduler...

Comment: @klausduisburg - What's the program called?

Comment: I wrote a few lines myself in autoit.
So it is my own exe. When the exe is not running for whatever reason that I would like to get notified.
When I use, for example, a notification in the code of the exe itself then it obviously only works when to exe closes as expected. But not when it fails for whatever other reason.
I could also write another exe that is checking if the other exe is running, but I thought there might be an option in the task scheduler... But seems that this is not the case!?

Comment: I am still wondering, doesn't Windows log the termination of a program at all?

Comment: In general, this isn't something a casual user handles unless the capabilities are built into the application.  Developers can add code to integrate with the event log, but generally only do so as a way to troubleshoot/resolve system issues. (See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/seealso/archive/2011/06/08/use-this-not-this-logging.aspx for one introduction.)   You might consider updating your app to modify a file every so often (say once a minute) and then use a second app to poll the file to make sure it's been updated in an acceptable period of time.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Seems that I will use a second application checking if the first application is running.